# Splashscreen motionLayout Listener, startActivity when finished

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am checking this tutorial on creating a splashscreen with Android Studio and motionLayout.

https://proandroiddev.com/android-motionlayout-twitter-splash-screen-57323ee97855

The tutorial is using motionLayout and keyframes to create a spashscreen animation. Then, set a listener on motionLayout to know each state of the transition. On transition completed, call startActivity to call the new activity (SecondActivity).

The problem is, the code below is in Kotlin and I am in Java.

My question is, is there a java alternative to this so I can call my SecondActivity when the motionLayout finishes playing? I'm not familiar enough to know if it can be converted easily. I am new to Android.

```
motionLayout.setTransitionListener(object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {
    override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int) {
        startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java))
    }
    override fun onTransitionChange(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Float) { }
    override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int) { }
    override fun onTransitionTrigger(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean, p3: Float) { }
})
```

The quick and dirty is to just add a timer, which I was able to do with something like below. But, the ideal would be a motion listener in java.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: in your Java code, start typing `motionLayout.setTransitionListener (new MotionLayout.TransitionListener` and let code completion get you going...

Answer (score 0):

```
motionLayout.setTransitionListener(new TransitionAdapter() {
public void onTransitionChange(MotionLayout motionLayout, int startId, int endId, float progress) {
}

public void onTransitionCompleted(MotionLayout motionLayout, int currentId) {
}
public void onTransitionStarted(MotionLayout motionLayout, int startId, int endId) {
}
public void onTransitionTrigger(MotionLayout motionLayout, int triggerId, boolean positive, float progress) {
}
});
```

Using the TransitionAdapter is better to use
All MotionLayout and ConstraintLayout is written in Java
[We have lots of examples](https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/tree/main/projects)

[Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/motion/widget/MotionLayout.TransitionListener)